# Is it natural and correct to say "the fire happened on its own" meaning it wasn't made intentionally by someone?

Tags: grammar

Is it natural and correct to say *the fire happened on its own* meaning it wasn't made intentionally by someone? For example:

> What we know for sure is that **the fire happened on its own**.

If it's not natural, what would a native English speaker would say?

Comment: A fire can start/break out/go out/blaze/burn/rage...

Comment: *What we know for sure is that [**the fire was spontaneous***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+fire+was+spontaneous%22) - or more "properly", *The **cause** of the fire was **spontaneous combustion / ignition***. Native speakers wouldn't often use ***happened** on its own* of something like a fire / blaze, but ***started*** isn't quite so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one normally would say:

> The fire ***started*** on its own.

You can check [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fire%20%2A%20on%20its%20own&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfire%20%2A%20on%20its%20own%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfire%20risk%20on%20its%20own%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfire%20started%20on%20its%20own%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfire%20line%20on%20its%20own%3B%2Cc0) for words that are commonly used in such a word order.

Another way of expressing this is:

> The fire was not lit deliberately.

OR

> The fire was not an arson.

I found these examples on the [greenpeace.org site](https://www.greenpeace.org/international/story/28252/fact-check-australias-unprecedented-fires-are-down-to-climate-change-not-arson/). However, my last two examples are a bit far from your sentence, and I am not sure if you are more interested in the form of your sentence or in the meaning you wish to convey.